# How to click on a link using partial link text

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm relatively new to python and selenium. How do I click on a link using partial link text using WebDriverWait.
I have the following working snippet for clicking with x_path

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "#my_xpath"))).click()
```

Comment: `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` works only on `<a>` tags. Why do you want to do it anyway?

Comment: @Guy  Yes I'm using only to click on <a> tags, need it to click on a page that is full of links and I want to search the link based on user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`, but be aware it works only on `<a>` tags

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, text))).click()
```

You can also use `xpath` `f'//*[contains(., "{text}")]'` to locate by partial text, in all tags

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//*[contains(., "{text}")]'))).click()
```